# How to keep the socket alive until the window is close Java

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to implement this program that will allow the user to upload/download the file from the server (both the client.java and server.java running in the same machine)

[image]

The problem that I have is when they choose the file and click the button to upload it will not allow them to upload the second time because the socket is not alive anymore.

How do I make sure that I can get the socket to stay alive until the window is close?

Comment: If your file server is HTTP, then you can't enfore the server to keep opened connection. Server admin, though, can :)

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk this is all done in the local machine?

Comment: Which protocol do you use? Can you show some code?

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk I will update the code as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you [set up your socket properly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html), use a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html):

```
// Listens for closing event
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        // Do stuff
        socket.close(); // Make sure socket is visible here
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but not successful... Maybe I misunderstood something on this method?

Comment: @Ali Make sure the socket is visible at that point. If it is, this will work fine.  If it does not work, the error is somewhere else in your source code.

Comment: I might have put the connect socket (new connection) in the wrong place.